# How to use FieldPath.of() in Firebase Firestore with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update a nested document field in Firebase Firestore, but when I use the FieldPath instance, It raises a compiler exception

```dart
    Map _map = {
      'name': 'vin',
      'quantity': 2,
      'costPrice': 12000,
    };
    var fieldPath = new FieldPath(['categories', 'branch']);
    final CollectionReference _storeRef =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('stores');
    _storeRef.doc('6').update({fieldPath: _map});
```

How do I update a nested document Field using the Firebase FieldPath instance

Comment: Please include the compiler exception in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DocumentReference.update](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentReference/update.html) method requires a `Map<String, dynamic>` as it's first parameter and the reason for the compiler error is because you're trying to pass a [FieldPath](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/FieldPath-class.html) object instead of a String.

You can [reduce](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/reduce.html) the values of the `FieldPath` into a String and use that as the path for the update method.

Update this:

```dart
    _storeRef.doc('6').update({fieldPath: _map});
```

to this:

```dart
_storeRef
        .doc('6')
        .update({'${fieldPath.components.reduce((a, b) => '$a.$b')}': _map});
```

This basically means the same as:

```dart
_storeRef
        .doc('6')
        .update({'categories.branch': _map});
```